# ERROR: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, splash-screen, filenotfoundexception

I recently tried to add a launch(splash) screen to my app, But an error is occurring all the time i try to run the app by the emulator.
this is the error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.aidin.workbook, PID: 29714
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aidin.workbook/com.aidin.workbook.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.aidin.workbook:drawable/background_splash with resource ID #0x7f07005c
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
                  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
                  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
                  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.aidin.workbook:drawable/background_splash with resource ID #0x7f07005c
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_splash.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07005c
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:821)
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:630)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:877)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:819)
                  at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:626)
                  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:87)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
                  at com.aidin.workbook.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:13)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7117)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7108)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
                  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
                  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:101)
                  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

My Android Studio, Gradle and Build tools all are up to date,
I tried to clean and rebuild the project for many times but it didn't help and non of the related answers out there were useful for this issue; I tried all of theme.
this is my style.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and this is my background_splash.xml in res/drawable directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"

        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

and this is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aidin.workbook">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Finally here is SplashActivity.java:

```
package com.aidin.workbook;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

this the Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aidin.workbook"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0-rc1"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:2.2.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ***background_splash.xml***,you have to change **bitmap src file to a drawable file that has to be in png format not in xml format**
like this **drawbles/ic_launcher.png**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"

        android:src=“@drawble/ic_launcher" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- <item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" /> -->

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

comment the contents inside  as above